# Where do you store long/complete queries used in code?

Tags: sql

Here's my situation. I've noticed that code gets harder to maintain when you keep embedding queries in every function that will use them. Some queries tend to grow very fast and tend to lose readability after concatenating every line. Another issue that comes with all of the concatenation is when you must test a specific query and paste it. You are forced to remove all of the " that held your query string together.

So my question is, what methods are being used to separate queries from the code? I have tried searching but it doesn't look like it's the right thing because i'm not finding anything relevant.

I'd like to note that views and stored procedure are not possible since my queries fetch data from a production database.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I avoid this problem by wrapping queries in classes that represent the entities stored in the table.  So the accounts table has an Account object.  It'll have an insert/update/delete query.

I've seen places where the query is stored in a file and templates are used to replace parts of the query.

Java had something called SQLJ - don't know if it ever took off.

LINQ might provide some way around this as an issue too.

Comment: SQLJ exists in some Database mangers such as DB2 and Oracle. It takes the sql code and precompiles it in the database, so it needs to access the database at compile time in order to create the data access plans.

Answer (score 4):

If you follow an [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller), then your queries should be all in the model - i.e. the objects representing actual data.

If not, then you could just put all your repetitive queries in script files, including only those needed in each request.

However, concatenating and that kind of stuff is hard to get rid of; that's why programmers exist :)

Answer (score 4):

These two words will be your best friend:  Stored Procedure

Comment: -1, even worse than embedded.

Comment: @NeilN- Please elaborate how SP can be worse than embedded?

Comment: +1, way better than an embedded string concat messs!

Comment: SPs are oversold, but I think this should lead one to avoid them.

Comment: There's no magic in a SP that prevents string concat mess if the query has a lot of conditionally unneeded components. If the user doesn't want the values by date, the where part doing date comparisons is dropped. Only string concat can do this.

Comment: I work on an app with over 1k tables (& it isn't some wacked schema altered by the app) & at least three times that many stored procs. There is no way on earth to have all that SQL in the app code.

Comment: @jmucchiello if the user doesn't want to filter by date there are ways to write a query around that. http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2005.html

Comment: I'd really like to know how they're even worse than embedded SQL.

Answer (score 3):

Risking being accused of not answering the question, my suggestion to you would be simply don't. Use an O/RM of your choice and you'll see this problem disappear in no time.

Answer (score 2):

I usually create a data class that represents the data requirements for objects that are represented in the database.  So if I have a customer class, then I create a customerData class as well that houses all the data access logic in them.  This keeps data logic out of your entity classes.  You would add all you CRUD methods here as well as custom data methods.

Youc an also use Stored Proceedures or an ORM tool depending on your language.

The main key is to get your data logic away from your business and entity logic.

Answer (score 0):

I use stored procedures in my production environment, and we process the rows too...